# objective-c card flip set image for both sites

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to create a flashcard app, I tried this code but its displays only the first image.

Any one can help me?

```
@implementation CardsViewController
- (IBAction)Flip:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if ([sender.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"]])
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b"]
                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"a"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like a very inefficient and potentially troublesome way to compare images. Just set up a boolean status flag and check that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hear is the simple way

hope this helps u ..

```
 @interface ViewController ()
 {
    BOOL ButtonClicked;//to trake change images ..
 }

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

    [super viewDidLoad];
     ButtonClicked = NO;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            //change the type of button to custom in the xib
 }

 - (IBAction)whenClicked:(id)sender
 {
     if(ButtonClicked)
     {
        ButtonClicked = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.button cache:YES];
        [self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }];



    }
    else
    {
        ButtonClicked = YES;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.button cache:YES];
        [self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }];
    }

 }
```

Comment: Looks like this will work for sure, I ll let you know. Thanks a lot Shan.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the background image, but using the "currentImage," i.e. foreground image as the comparison.

Try replacing:

```
if ([sender.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"]])
```

with

```
if ([sender.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"]])
```

Comment: A couple things -- (1) Are you sure everything's hooked up correctly and the IBAction's being called? (2) When you've written imageNamed "a" and "b", you're actually following it up with a file type in your code, right? Such as "a.png". And (3) are you sure you've originally set the background image and not the foreground image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a View contain two subviews, then just transition them ,***[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]***

***code snippet:***

```
UIButton *containerView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
containerView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 120.0);
[containerView addTarget:self action:@selector(transition:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample1"];
imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample2"];
imageView1.tag = 1;
imageView2.tag = 2;

[containerView addSubview:imageView1];
[containerView addSubview:imageView2];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];

- (void)transition:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView *)[sender viewWithTag:1];
    UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView *)[sender viewWithTag:2];

    static NSInteger index = 0;
    index++;
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        [UIView transitionFromView:imageView1 toView:imageView2 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews completion:NULL];
    } else {
        [UIView transitionFromView:imageView2 toView:imageView1 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to use single button :)

Comment: @user3344744 just add your subviews to the single button :D

Comment: looks so complicated :) i'm a beginner, can't we make it simple?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background image, one way you can achieve the flip effect is by using the UIButton states and, set one of your images as default image for the 'Normal' state and the other image as default image for the 'Selected' state; you could even set those images at design time and then only change the state of your button through your method Flip which will automatically change the image shown to the user.

Please note that for each button state you can set two images, a default image and a background image. You don't even need/have to set a background image or keep changing it every time the button is selected.

```
@implementation CardsViewController
- (IBAction)Flip:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if ([sender isSelected])
    {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }

}
```

If you want or need to set your images through code, add these lines in a method that fires one time only, typically ViewDidLoad:

```
[yourButtonInstance setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButtonInstance setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```